# How to achieve a smooth transition from exiting and closing Flutter applications with ListViews

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm simply trying to archive a **behaviour** like this:

https://streamable.com/vnvxt0

When a scroll is performed, notice how it sort of fades in and out after exiting and returning to the application.

On the other hand, with a flutter application, it doesn't behave in such this way. Rather it forces itself to the correct scroll position:

https://streamable.com/omztmj

A minimal code example would be the Flutter Hello world app with a Listview.builder()

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

// Root class called by the runApp() method.

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              title: Text(
                'test',
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 50,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any form of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the behavior are not the same? Because there is a small jump in Tweeter too, it just looks to me as if you scrolled faster in the flutter app therefore increasing the effect

Comment: I'm certain the behaviours are very different. It might be true I scrolled a bit faster over at the Flutter app, but through trail and error, I'm sure they different still.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the behavior is different on IOS and Android. Can you test this? (Also I did some test and app like Youtube have very strange behavior when doing the test at high speed)